# Input type button changes color while pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, dom-events

I want my input type=button to change color only while pressed. For example, if I have a white button, I want it to become green only while pressed, and when it's no more pressed I wish it returns white. How can I do this in HTML and Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

the CSS selector for this state is called `:active`

So if you do:

`input.btn:active { background:green }`

that should work.

See **[demo](http://jsbin.com/ekigeb/1/edit)**

Comment: @Trekstuff which IE? For elements other than a it is supported in IE only from 8.0 version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:active .

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski in IE9 actually. Funny thing it looks like if I click on button *outside of button text* it works. But if I click on actual button text - it doesn't

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski it works universally if I use `button` element instead of `input` element, e.g. `<button type="button" class="btn">aaaa</button>` instead of `<input type="button" class="btn" value="aaaa" />`

Comment: @xdazz: That's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Plain vanilla HTML + JavaSctipt:

```
<input type="button" style="background-color:white" value="Click Me" onmousedown="this.style.background='green'" onmouseup="this.style.background='white'" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bqjzq/

Comment: Why would you do javascript, esp. inline javascript for something like this if you can do it with CSS?

Comment: See my comments to Piotr solution below. Pure CSS for input button does not work in IE. And inline JS is just for the example, of course if a more complex function is needed it should be a function. Anyway pure CSS workd for <button> element, so if author is not bound to <input> element - JS solution is not needed. (Of course if support for browsers below IE8 is needed - JS is the only solution)

Comment: I wanna find a solution where it also works if you release the mousebutton outside of the target

Answer (score 1):

For me it only works with:

```
<style>
input:active{  background-color:green}
</style>
```

Another option is to specify on mouse over, for buttons only:

```
<style>
input[type=button]:hover{  background-color: #46000D}
<style>
```